# How to output sequence elements and total in expl3

Tags: expl3

Suppose, I have a sequence of numbers: {1,2,3}. I want to output it like this:

1 + 2 + 3 = 6

I created this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% The following three macros are well defined
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfpvar}{m}{\fp_new:N #1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}{\fp_set:Nn #1 { #2 }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getfpvar}{m}{\fp_use:N #1}

 \cs_new_protected:Npn \mmmmxxxv_define_fp_var:Nn #1 #2
 {
     \cs_if_exist:NF #1
     {
         \fp_new:N #1
         \fp_set:Nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
 }

%#1 - sequence name
%#2 - value
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mmmmxxxv_seq_put_fp_var_right:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mmmmxxxv_fp_seq
\mmmmxxxv_seq_put_fp_var_right:Nn \l_mmmmxxxv_fp_seq { 1 }
\mmmmxxxv_seq_put_fp_var_right:Nn \l_mmmmxxxv_fp_seq { 2 }
\mmmmxxxv_seq_put_fp_var_right:Nn \l_mmmmxxxv_fp_seq { 3 }

\tl_new:N \__text
\mmmmxxxv_define_fp_var:Nn{\Total}{0}
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mmmmxxxv_fp_seq
 {
   %here I don't understand, how to check that we are processing the last
   %element of sequence and don't put '+'
   \tl_put_right:Nx \__text {\getfpvar{#1} +}
   \fp_add:Nn \Total #1
 }
\show\__text
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
%want to show here: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 --- \__text = \getfpvar{\Total}
\getfpvar{\Total}
\end{document}
```

It creates a sequence, calculates the total and tries to store the numbers in __text variable. \show__text prints this:

```
> \__text=macro:
->\getfpvar {1}+\getfpvar {2}+\getfpvar {3}+.
```

\Total is correct

But when I try to output __text, it gives an error:

```
! Use of \__fp_to_decimal_dispatch:w doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> 1
```

Comment: You're making the same error you did in the other question: don't use high level macros like `\getfpvar` in lower level code.

Comment: And please learn the name convention. Your local token list is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an implementation of what you seem to want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\storefpvalues}{mm}
 {
  \mmmmxxxv_store_fpvalues:nn {#1}{#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumfpsequence}{m}
 {
  \mmmmxxxv_sum_fp_sequence:n {#1}
 }

% internal functions

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mmmmxxxv_store_fpvalues:nn #1 #2
 {
  % if the sequence doesn't exist, define it
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } }
  % add the values
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } { \fp_eval:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mmmmxxxv_sum_fp_sequence:n #1
 {% evaluate the sum of the entries
  \fp_eval:n { 0 + \seq_use:cnnn { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } { + } { + } { + } }
 }

% since \seq_use:cnnn doesn't exist, we create it
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\storefpvalues{test}{1,2,3}

\sumfpsequence{test}

\end{document}
```

You can use `\storefpvalues` to (locally) add to the symbolically named sequence `test`; the internal name will be `\l__mmmmxxxv_store_test_seq`, but at the user level this is unimportant, therefore I used a “private” name with prefix `l__`. The addition is incremental, so the calls

```
\storefpvalues{test}{1,2}
\storefpvalues{test}{3}
```

would be equivalent.

You can also call

```
\storefpvalues{testb}{1+2,sin(pi/2)}
```

and the result of `\sumfpsequence{testb}` would be 4.

With `\sumfpsequence{test}` you compute the sum of all the stored entries.

You can also call, say,

```
\storefpvalues{testb}{1+2,sin(pi/2)}
```

and the result of `\sumfpsequence{testb}` would be 4.

---

If you also want to show the summand, here's a modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\storefpvalues}{mm}
 {
  \mmmmxxxv_store_fpvalues:nn {#1}{#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumfpsequence}{m}
 {
  \mmmmxxxv_sum_fp_sequence:n {#1}
 }

% internal functions

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mmmmxxxv_store_fpvalues:nn #1 #2
 {
  % if the sequence doesn't exist, define it
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } }
  % add the values
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } { \fp_eval:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mmmmxxxv_sum_fp_sequence:n #1
 {% print the summands with `+` in between
  $
  \group_begin:
  % detach the first item and print it
  \seq_pop_left:cN { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
  \l_tmpa_tl
  % now print the next value preceded by + if non negative
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq }
   {
    \fp_compare:nF { ##1 < 0 } { + }
    ##1
   }
  \group_end: % this will revert the change to the sequence
  =
  % evaluate the sum of the entries
  \fp_eval:n { 0 + \seq_use:cnnn { l__mmmmxxxv_store_#1_seq } { + } { + } { + } }
  $
 }

% since \seq_use:cnnn doesn't exist, we create it
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\storefpvalues{test}{1,-2,sin(pi/2)}

\sumfpsequence{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]